# I want to see the full git history of the recovered file after it was removed from Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

see this:

1. Add file A.java.
2. Remove file A.java.
3. Add File A.java.
4. Click file A.java's `show history` in Intellij
5. I only see a third commit from A.java

Can I see all history of A.java file in Intellij?
In Git-bash and Eclipse(STS), I can see all the history I want.

Please help me.

Comment: In general, it is difficult to trace a file in Git through removals/additions, or renaming operations.  I think the limitation here would be Git, and not IntelliJ (I use both by the way).

Comment: Thanks for your attention. When I asked JetBrains, it was an issue that was being resolved. [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132215#tab=Comments)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question to JetBrains, an Intellij developer, who told me it was a duplicate issue.
The issue is currently registered as a major issue in jetBrains and seems to be resolved in the Intellij 2017.1 version.

jetBrains issue [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132215#tab=Comments)